# How to integrate Asp.Net MVC existing application to MAUI Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I have an existing Asp.Net MVC web application. I want to integrate my existing MVC web application into the MAUI framework without any new development.

I want to just create wrapping up the code

Comment: Not possible. Maui is not compatible with an ASP.Net web application. Those are very different technologies. A major code rewrite is required. Either learn to code Maui UI and read [Strategies for migrating ASP.NET web forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/porting-existing-aspnet-apps/migrate-web-forms) OR rewrite the web application in Blazor, so you can use Maui Blazor.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve  Thank you for your response! I have two questions for MAUI

Basically, I need to my MVC logic also re-write on MAUI C#. Am i right?
Can we use any frontend library like Jquery, AngularJS, Angular ?

Comment: I don't use the Blazor part of Maui, so I don't know about using frontend libraries, nor the pros and cons of keeping your javascript code. You will write some c#. Search `blazor javascript` for discussions of mixing c# and javascript. [ASP.NET Core Blazor JavaScript interoperability (JS interop)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) is a document to start with. If you are not familiar already with c# and ASP.Net, look for videos and blogs that may be easier to understand.